# Create a Proxy for an RTSP Stream in Golang using mediamtx due to bandwidth challenges at the source which is an IP Camera

Tags: go, proxy, video-streaming, rtsp

I have visited the official github page of the MediaMtx https://github.com/aler9/mediamtx

- I first downloaded and launched the image using the following command

```
docker run --rm -it --network=host aler9/rtsp-simple-server
```

- Then I have edited the mediamtx.yml file with the following changes in the path section where I have mentioned my source url.

```
paths:
  proxied:
    # url of the source stream, in the format rtsp://user:pass@host:port/path
    source: rtsp://original-url
```

- The command I used to edit the yml was `docker run --rm -it --network=host -v $PWD/mediamtx.yml:/mediamtx.yml aler9/rtsp-simple-server`
- Now as the documentation says I tried to listen to the proxied address which is rtsp://localhost:8554/proxied, but I am getting the error as exit 1.
- This is the ffmpeg command I am using to read the stream using a different program locally
  `cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-rtsp_transport", "tcp", "-re", "-i", "rtsp://localhost:8854/proxied", "-c:v", "copy", "-f", "segment", "-segment_time", "300", "-segment_format", "mp4", "-segment_list", "recordings/playlist.m3u8", "-segment_list_entry_prefix", "recordings/", "-nostdin", "recordings/output-%03d.mp4")` Where Im storing the stream as mp4 files on a timely basis.

I tried to add user authentication(rtsp://user:pass@host:port/path) to the paths section of the yml hoping that was the issue

```
paths:
  all:
    readUser: user
    readPass: userpass
```

But this did not seem to work. Got no clue as to which direction to look into as Im new to RTSP protocol. Hope this sums up my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. create docker container.
   docker run --name rtps-proxy -it -e MTX_PROTOCOLS=tcp  -p 8554:8554 -p 1935:1935 -p 8888:8888 -p 8889:8889 -d bluenviron/mediamtx
2. edit mediamtx.yml

paths:
proxied:
# url of the source stream, in the format rtsp://user:pass@host:port/path
source: rtsp://original-url

3. copy mediamtx.yml to docker container

docker cp mediamtx.yml rtps-proxy:/mediamtx.yml

docker restart rtps-proxy container

you can watch video at http://host:8888/proxied on browser